# Как разделить путь на базовое имя файла и путь?

Tags: golang, файловая-система, path

<sup>(Перевод
[вопроса с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34527672/1892060).)</sup>

Как в *Go* разделить путь на базовое имя файла и путь?  То есть,
имея `"/some/path/to/remove/file.name"` я хочу получить
`"/some/path/to/remove/"` и `"file.name"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Перевод
[ответа с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34527720/1892060).)</sup>

С помощью функций
[`filepath.Base`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Base)
и
[`filepath.Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Dir):

```golang
const path = "/some/path/to/remove/file.name"
fmt.Println(filepath.Base(path))
fmt.Println(filepath.Dir(path))
// Output:
//
//   file.name
//   /some/path/to/remove
```

*Playground:*
https://play.golang.org/p/V9-mpXib1EZ.